# Can we prevent assignment to innerHTML from requesting resources?

Tags: javascript, dom

The following code results in an HTTP request for an image resource in both Firefox and Chrome.

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = "<img src='junk'/>";
```

As a programmer, I may or may not want `el` to be rendered. If I don't, then maybe I don't want a request being sent for the src.

`dojo.toDom()` shows the same behaviour.

Is there anyway to get a document fragment from a string, without referenced resources from being requested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`DOMParser`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250545/javascript-domparser-access-innerhtml-and-other-properties/9251106#9251106) to create a full document structure from a given string.

Alternatively, use the [`beforeload`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395525/safari-extension-beforeload-event-documentation) event to intercept requests.

Comment: PS. Demo for method 1: http://jsfiddle.net/4rkUU/. Method 2 is only available to Webkit extensions.

Answer (score -2):

Much lighter memory to use strings to create DOM elements instead of creating documentFragments and working with them:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = 'some text';
document.getElementById('someparent').appendChild('div');
```

Can be replaced with:

```
var div = '<div>some text</div>';
document.getElementById('someparent').innerHTML += div;
```

Comment: I don't believe this is what was asked in the question. Read it again. -1