# How to prevent permanently the ability to assign the function onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, safari, safari-extension

Here is what I'm trying to solve: I never want to be asked again if I really want to close a window. Unfortunately, some people think it's a good idea to add an alert() in `onbeforeunload` (or similar functions) to make their page stay longer on the screen.

Is it possible, permanently and for everything, to prevent onbeforeunload from begin redefined ?

For example, inside a Safari extension, is it possible to catch a modification made to `onbeforeunload` and prevent it ?

Comment: Could you post the code you've tried?  Are you requesting to block these popups, *outside of your code*, on other webpages?

Comment: I'm not trying to block them, I'm trying to prevent any Javascript code to assign onbeforeunload, or at least a method to detect that it has been assigned and react. I have no code right now, I'm looking for the different methods to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that would be a "too broad" question. You're expected to ask here about concrete implementation problems after having tried to do so.

Comment: I understand you're new, but here's a good [blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) to check out. Here's a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395525/safari-extension-beforeload-event-documentation) that may help get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is possible using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). You need to manage to execute the following code in the execution context of all webpages where you want to block that property:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'onbeforeunload', {value: null});
```

In a Chrome extension you can achieve that using a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) that runs in `<all_urls>` and `all_frames` at `document_start`, and using some of the techniques described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/1507998) to make the code run in the execution context of the page. For a Safari extension it should be more or less the same.

Note that a page could still register a `beforeunload` handler using `window.addEventListener`. To prevent that from happening you could add to the previous line of code something like:

```
(function() {
    var prevFunc = window.addEventListener;
    window.addEventListener = function( name ) { 
        if( name !== 'beforeunload' )
            return prevFunc.apply(window, arguments);
    }
})();
```